# How to prevent EMR Spark step from retrying?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I have an AWS EMR cluster (emr-4.2.0, Spark 1.5.2), where I am submitting steps from aws cli. My problem is, that if the Spark application fails, then YARN is trying to run the application again (under the same EMR step).
How can I prevent this?

I was trying to set `--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1`, which is correctly set in Environment/Spark Properties, but it doesn't prevent YARN from restarting the application.

Comment: Have you looked at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709280/how-to-limit-the-number-of-retries-on-spark-job-failure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the number of retries on Spark job failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709280/how-to-limit-the-number-of-retries-on-spark-job-failure)