# How to limit the number of retries on Spark job failure?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

We are running a Spark job via `spark-submit`, and I can see that the job will be re-submitted in the case of failure.

How can I stop it from having attempt #2 in case of yarn container failure or whatever the exception be?

[image]

This happened due to lack of memory and "GC overhead limit exceeded" issue.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are two settings that control the number of retries (i.e. the maximum number of `ApplicationMaster` registration attempts with YARN is considered failed and hence the entire Spark application):

- `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts` - Spark's own setting. See [MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/config.scala#L61-L65):

  ```
    private[spark] val MAX_APP_ATTEMPTS = ConfigBuilder("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts")
      .doc("Maximum number of AM attempts before failing the app.")
      .intConf
      .createOptional
  ```
- `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` - YARN's own setting with default being 2.

(As you can see in [YarnRMClient.getMaxRegAttempts](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.0.0/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/yarn/YarnRMClient.scala#L124-L133)) the actual number is the minimum of the configuration settings of YARN and Spark with YARN's being the last resort.

Comment: Since it appears we can use either option to set the max attempts to 1 (since a minimum is used), is one preferable over the other, or would it be a better practice to set both to 1?

Comment: @EvilTeach Links fixed. Let me know if you need anything else to make the answer better. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 40):

An API/programming language-agnostic solution would be to set the yarn max attempts as a command line argument:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 <application_name>
```

See @code 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41611520/7004653)

Answer (score 8):

Add the property `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` to your yarn-default.xml file. It specifies the maximum number of application attempts.

For more details look into this [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)

Answer (score 0):

but in general in which cases - it would fail once and recover at the second time - in case of  cluster or queue too busy I guess
I am running jobs using oozie coordinators - I was thinking to set to `1` - it it fails it will run at the next materialization -