# spark on yarn run double times when error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I use the model that spark on yarn,when i meet a problem the spark would restart automatic.

I want to run exact once whatever successful or fail.

Is there any conf or api can set?

I'm using spark version 1.5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to set `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts` property to 1. Default value for this is `yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts` which is by default 2.

Set the property via code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.set("spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts", "1");
```

Set when submitting the job via spark-submit:

> --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1

Comment: it's ok,and i want to know  how to get this key “spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts” .i never see it in source code or docs.

Comment: thanks,I have seen it in site http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/running-on-yarn.html.