# EMR on EKS | Spark job retries 5 times if failed

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-emr

I am using the release: `emr-5.33.0-latest`

Whenever a spark job fails, it tries to restart 5 times. I am not able to find where this behavior is configured or if its something default, and how to disable this.

I also tried the below by using 6.9.0 emr release. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-on-EKS-DevelopmentGuide/jobruns-using-retry-policies.html

Even after configuring

```
"retryPolicyConfiguration": {
    "maxAttempts": 1
}
```

It retried it 5 times if it failed.

Does anyone know how to debug this and disable this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of job is it? There a variety of technologies supported on EMR. For example, Spark has its own configuration, including retries.

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin my bad. Its a spark job

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709280/how-to-limit-the-number-of-retries-on-spark-job-failure

Comment: You could try setting `spark.task.maxFailures`.  See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html